# RMI invocation semantics

Tags: java, client-server, rmi, semantics

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface Account extends Remote {
    public void deposit (double amount)
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public void withdraw (double amount) 
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public double getBalance()
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public void setBalance(double balance)
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}

public interface Branch extends Remote {
    public void create (String name)
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public void lookup (String name)
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public double branchTotal()
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

RMI provides three invocation semantics: *Maybe semantics*, *At-least-once semantics*, *At-most-once semantics*. Based on these 3 semantics, what would I need to change in the mentioned interfaces (*Account* and *Branch*)?

Comment: What do you think you would need to change? So far you only dropped requirements. Reads a little bit like you want us to do your homework for you.

Comment: @GhostCat, this is just a practice question that im doing. I just don't get what i would need to change in *interfaces* in order to reflect each of those semantics.

Answer (score 0):

> RMI provides three invocation semantics: Maybe semantics, At-least-once semantics, At-most-once semantics.

No it doesn't. Java RMI provides *at-most-once* invocation semantics only. This applies to RMI/JRMP, RMI/IIOP, and RMI/JERI. Can't speak for any others.

> Based on these 3 semantics, what would I need to change in the mentioned interfaces (Account and Branch)?

Nothing. There is no way to change the invocation semantics whatsoever.